# Always get "TypeError: str.match(...) is null"

Tags: javascript, match

does anyone know why I always get "TypeError: str.match(...) is null" in Firefox console when executing this JS-Method?

```
function checkBreakPoints() {
    var str = '@media only screen and (max-width:2em)';
    var patt1 ="/@media[A-z, 0-9, \-,: , ., ), (]*width:/gi";
    console.log(str.match(patt1).length);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Character classes aren't comma-separated...

Comment: Also, `patt1` shouldn't be in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from your invalid character class syntax (should be `[A-Za-z0-9:. ()-]`), then main problem is that you are creating a string, not a regex literal. Remove the quotes from around it.

```
var patt1 = /@media[A-Z0-9:. ()-]*width:/gi;
```

Comment: Since it's case insensitive it only needs to be `/@media[A-Z0-9:. ()-]*width:/gi` or `/@media[a-z0-9:. ()-]*width:/gi`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight Correctamundo! A word I have never used before and probably will never use again...

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

it says that str.match(patt1)  will return null if there is no matches, so you cant do:  `null.length`

Check to see if it is not null before doing the `.length`

```
var a = "hi", b = "no", c = a.match(b);
console.log(c.length);
```

error.

While the pattern the OP wanted to create was improperly done....   he wanted to make a regex, my answer was sound for his base question as to why the strings are not comparing correctly and is returning null.   The def of match, says it is looking for a regex, `/[a-z]+/` for example and not a string.

Comment: would love a reason as to why i was give a downvote.  Thanks.